# delete data from multiple tables when joined all tables php larvel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a problem in my code. I have to delete the data using id from 5 tables, those tables joined by primary key and foreign key.

This is what I tried but it will show adding subscription table id. But already added subscription table id.

```
$subscription = DB::table('tbl_asset_subscription')->where('id',$post['asset_id'])->get();
        foreach($subscription as $row)
        {
        DB::table('tbl_asset_subscription')->where('id',$row->id)->delete();
        }

        $orderId = array();

        foreach($subscription as $row)
        {
        $order = DB::table('tbl_asset_order')->where('subscription_id',$row->id)->first();
        $orderId[] = $order->id;

        }


        foreach($orderId as $row)
        {
        DB::table('tbl_asset_payment')->where('order_id',$row->id)->delete();
        DB::table('tbl_asset_order')->where('id',$row->id)->delete();
        }





        DB::table('tbl_asset_versions')->where('asset_id',$post['asset_id'])->delete();
        DB::table('tbl_assets')->where('id',$post['asset_id'])->delete();

        // DB::table('tbl_asset_subscription')->where('asset_id',$post['asset_id'])->delete();
        echo(json_encode(array("result" => true)));
```

```
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`piccoscript`.`tbl_asset_subscription`, CONSTRAINT `fk_tbl_asset_subscription_tbl_assets` FOREIGN KEY (`asset_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_assets` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION) (SQL: delete from `tbl_assets` where `id` = 1)",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/var/www/html/piccoscript/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
    "line": 664,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/piccoscript/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 624,
            "function": "runQueryCallback",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can temporarily disable a foreign key constrain

In Laravel you can do the following:

```
$orderId = array();
$subscription = DB::table('tbl_asset_subscription')->where('id',$post['asset_id'])->get(); 
DB::transaction(function() {

    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0');
    foreach($subscription as $row) {
        DB::table('tbl_asset_subscription')->where('id', $row->id)->delete();
    }

    foreach($subscription as $row) {
        $order = DB::table('tbl_asset_order')->where('subscription_id', $row->id)->first();
        $orderId[] = $order->id;

    }


    if($orderId) {
        DB::table('tbl_asset_payment')->whereIn('order_id', $orderId)->delete();
        DB::table('tbl_asset_order')->whereIn('id', $orderId )->delete();
    }

    DB::table('tbl_asset_versions')->where('asset_id', $post['asset_id'])->delete();
    DB::table('tbl_assets')->where('id', $post['asset_id'])->delete();
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1');

});
echo(json_encode(array("result" => true)));
```

Comment: @FarzanaBanu you disable foreign key checks for all tables inside that specific database. All you need to do is to paste your code between two statements. I will update my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

$orderId is not a associative array so error came. Try this code.

```
foreach($subscription as $row)
{
$order = DB::table('tbl_asset_order')->where('subscription_id',$row->id)->first();
$orderId[] = array(
        'id' => $order->id
    );

}


foreach($orderId as $row)
{
DB::table('tbl_asset_payment')->where('order_id',$row->id)->delete();
DB::table('tbl_asset_order')->where('id',$row->id)->delete();
}


DB::table('tbl_asset_versions')->where('asset_id',$post['asset_id'])->delete();
DB::table('tbl_assets')->where('id',$post['asset_id'])->delete();

// DB::table('tbl_asset_subscription')->where('asset_id',$post['asset_id'])->delete();
echo(json_encode(array("result" => true)));
```